when instaling react-native starter project / properlly not install
enter image description here

Downloading templateerror Installing pods failed. This doesn't affect project initialization and you can safely proceed.
However, you will need to install pods manually when running iOS, follow additional steps in "Run instructions for iOS" section.

× Downloading template
Run instructions for Android:
• Have an Android emulator running (quickest way to get started), or a device connected.
• cd "C:\Users\Neeraj Patel\Desktop\patel\AwesomeProject" && npx react-native run-android
Run instructions for Windows:
• See https://aka.ms/ReactNativeGuideWindows for the latest up-to-date instructions.

1)Check the name of the project
2)Check the path, must not contain special characters
3)Check the version of nodejs
4)Try to read the logs carefully, and see if there are any leading points to your issue.
5)If none of the above worked, try looking for a YouTube video to walk you through step by step.
6)If you are still learning react native I recommend a Udemy course by Maximilian Schwarzmüller.
